# Booting DBAN from PXE failing with non-fatal errors

Tags: pxe-boot, dban

I have a functioning PXE configuration that allows to boot to an installation by Kickstart or rescue, both via RHEL6 media.

I'm trying to add DBAN to the mix to make for a more complete solution for our needs. I have it set up to boot and it will load, but it keeps failing with

```
DBAN finished with non-fatal errors.
Check the log for more informatoin.
Hardware clock operation start date: Fri Jun 14 11:27:50 2013
Hardware clock operation finish date: Fri Jun 14 11:28:00 2013

 * ERROR /dev/sda (process crash)

Press and hold the power button to shutdown.
```

I can get it to load via CD without problem.

The PXE menu entry that I have is

```
label wipe
    kernel /images/dban/dban-226.bzi
    append initrd=/images/dban/dban-226.bzi root=/dev/ram0 init=rc
```

I've also tried without the root= or init= options with the same result.

I'm not even entirely sure about those options. Not much that I've found online gives much detail or explanation. One thing I know for sure, is that right now I don't want to enable the autonuke option. I simply want to load up the interactive method.

Has anyone been able to make this work?

EDIT: Potentially pertinent information
The server that I'm testing this on (and, in fact, 99% of our servers) are VMs running on VMware ESXi. The CD works when I attach it as an ISO to the VMware console and boot to it.

Answer (score 1):

After a few minutes I wised up and thought to look at the isolinux.cfg file from the DBAN ISO.  The only option after append that is common on all of them is 'nuke="dwipe"'. I put that option in place and the application loaded properly.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to ensure it works is to load the ISO directly:

```
LABEL DBAN
MENU LABEL DBAN - Wipe Hard Drive
LINUX memdisk
append iso raw
INITRD dban.iso
```

This loads the entire ISO through memdisk and boots it, so no matter what parameters the kernel is expecting, it should work.